# NReco HtmlToPdfConvertor on .NET Core throws HttpContext exception

Tags: c#, .net-core, nreco

When I declare the NReco.PdfGenerator in a .Net Core 2.0 Mvc application I get an error.

- I added the Nuget package NReco.PdfGenerator 1.1.15 to the project
- Made a using statement In the controller
- Declare the HtmlToPdfConverter

---

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult Index(myModel model)
{
    var html2PdfConverter = new NReco.PdfGenerator.HtmlToPdfConverter();
      
    // etc.   
}
```

It throws a

> Could not load type 'System.Web.HttpContext' from assembly 'System.Web, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'

directly on declaring it.

Has someone had experience with nReco?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I use this in .Net Core and reference the `NReco.PdfGenerator.LT` nuget package for Html to PDF conversion from NReco.

Comment: NReco.PdfGenerator.LT requires a license key

Answer (score 1):

use this:

```
var converter = new HtmlConverter();
var html = "<div><strong>Hello</strong> World!</div>";
var bytes = converter.FromHtmlString(html);
File.WriteAllBytes("image.jpg", bytes);
```

you need to install package:

```
Install-Package CoreHtmlToImage
```

Comment: Are you suggesting converting it to an image rather than pdf?

Comment: converting image to pdf is easy,

Comment: This question is about using NReco, and automating the creation of the PDF.